# How to refresh view using AJAX call in .NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

ASP.Net Core MVC 3.1, C#
I have a view where you can select photos. Once the photos have been selected I have a button which calls an AJAX routine which populates the formdata with all the files select and passes it to a method in my controller. This all works. But when I call my View again to refresh with new photos nothing happens. Below is my view code:

```
function uploadPhotos() {
    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');

    var input = document.getElementById("inpFiles");
    var files = input.files;
    var formData = new FormData();

    for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Photos/Create",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

And here is the Create method in my controller:

```
public IActionResult Create(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
    string ErrorPath = Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Errors");

    Int16 photoStage = 0;

    //Make sure a photo stage is selected.
    if (GetPhotoStage() == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GetPhotos", "Photos", new { customer_Id = GetCustomerId() });
    }

    List<ApplicationUser> users = userManager.Users.ToList();
    string FullName = users.Find(x => x.Email == User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)).FullName;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = null;
        //If customer Id sub folder in the photos folder does not exist create it.
        string photoFolder = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Photos"), GetCustomerId().ToString());
        photoStage = GetPhotoStage();
        photoFolder = Path.Combine(photoFolder, photoStage.ToString());
        if (!Directory.Exists(photoFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(photoFolder);
        }
        var logWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Path.Combine(ErrorPath, "Logaaaaaaa.txt"));
        logWriter.WriteLine("Got Here!");
        logWriter.Close();
        foreach (IFormFile photo in files)
        {
            uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
            string filePath = Path.Combine(photoFolder, uniqueFileName);
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            photo.CopyTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Close();
            fileStream.Dispose();
            shrinkPhoto(filePath);

            JobPhotos jobPhoto = new JobPhotos
            {
                CustomerId = GetCustomerId(),
                CreatedBy = FullName,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
                PhotoStage = photoStage,
                PhotoPath = GetCustomerId() + "/" + photoStage + "/" + uniqueFileName,
            };
            context.JobPhotos.Add(jobPhoto);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View("Photos", PopulateLists(GetCustomerId(), photoStage));
}
```

I hope I have done my post correctly.

In short the user select a list of photos, presses a button to save. The files information is added to formdata and passed to a method using an AJAX call. In the Create method in the controller it saves the photos. All this works. I then want to refresh the page as if I had just loaded it so I call the View but nothing happens.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi @user1633508. I edited your post. Please, try to use code samples for your controller, views, functions or methods, and avoid using snippets for code that cannot be executed independently and that is not capable to display a result by itself.

Comment: Thanks Dave for editing my post, much appreciated.